# PDO - PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on this small project and I can't move on. PDO is working perfectly in other queries, no problem there - I hope.
I've checked the site and the previously asked questions did not help me

this is my code:

```
try { //Step 1
$stmt_dataliiParinte = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO parintei (numeParinte, prenumeParinte, adresaParinte, localitateParinte, codpostalParinte, telefonParinte, mobilParinte, emailParinte, profesiaParinte, locmuncaParinte) VALUES (:numeParinte, :prenumeParinte, :adresaParinte, :localitateParinte, :codpostalParinte, :telefonParinte, :mobilParinte, :emailParinte, :profesiaParinte, :locmuncaParinte) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE emailParinte=VALUES(:emailParinte)');
print_r($stmt_dataliiParinte);
$stmt_detaliiParinte->execute(array(
    ':numeParinte' => $numeParinte,
    ':prenumeParinte' => $prenumeParinte,
    ':adresaParinte' => $adresaParinte,
    ':localitateParinte' => $localitateParinte,
    ':codpostalParinte' => $codpostalParinte,
    ':telefonParinte' => $phoneNumber,
    ':mobilParinte' => $phoneNumber2,
    ':emailParinte' => $emailParinte,
    ':profesiaParinte' => $profesiaParinte,
    ':locmuncaParinte' => $locmuncaParinte
));
$parinteID = $db->lastInsertId();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

this is the print_r($stmt_dataliiParinte):

```
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => INSERT INTO parintei (numeParinte, prenumeParinte, adresaParinte, localitateParinte, codpostalParinte, telefonParinte, mobilParinte, emailParinte, profesiaParinte, locmuncaParinte) VALUES (:numeParinte, :prenumeParinte, :adresaParinte, :localitateParinte, :codpostalParinte, :telefonParinte, :mobilParinte, :emailParinte, :profesiaParinte, :locmuncaParinte) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE emailParinte=VALUES(:emailParinte) )
```

so by the looks it's a PDOStatement object

I also tried to see if I have some variable error in the array so I also did an print_r on the execute array:

```
Array ( [:numeParinte] => dasda [:prenumeParinte] => dasdas [:adresaParinte] => dasdasd [:localitateParinte] => asdas [:codpostalParinte] => 23232 [:telefonParinte] => 1231231231231 [:mobilParinte] => 123123123123123 [:emailParinte] => x@x.com [:profesiaParinte] => asd [:locmuncaParinte] => dasdasdasd )
```

The names of the columns I've checked and double checked.
I also tried removing the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but with the same effect.

As I said before other queries work perfectly (example):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tabere (dentabara,locatie,datastart,dataend,desctabara,pageID,tip,pret) VALUES (:dentabara, :locatie, :datastart, :dataend, :desctabara, :pageID, :tip, :pret)') ;
                            $stmt->execute(array(
                                ':dentabara' => $dentabara,
                                ':locatie' => $locatie,
                                ':datastart' => $datastart,
                                ':dataend' => $dataend,
                                ':desctabara' => $desctabara,
                                ':pageID' => $paginaTabara,
                                ':tip' => $tip,
                                ':pret' => $pret
                            ));
```

Comment: Also, the `VALUES` clause in the `ON UPDATE` portion of the statement should reference a *column name*, not a bind variable. There's no need to repeat the same bind parameter twice. Specify **`VALUES(column)`**, to reference the *value* that would have been inserted to that *column*, if the insert had succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spot the difference:

```
$stmt_dataliiParinte = $db->prepare(' ... snip ...');
       ^
$stmt_detaliiParinte->execute(array( ... snip ...));
       ^
```